# How to get currentIndex of an delegateItem in a TreeView

Tags: qt, indexing, treeview, qml, qt-quick

Hellow,

When using `delegate` on a `Column`, how could I know the index of the `Cell` or `Row` selected if the user clicks on the `delegateItem` ?

Here is an example. The second `Column` is a `MouseArea` and I want to `expand` the `currentIndex` when the user clicks on the `MouseArea`:

```
TreeView {
    id: view
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"
        width: 300
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Permissions"
        role: "filePermissions"
        width: 100
        delegate : MouseArea {
            id:mous
            onClicked {
                 //get indexMouseArea
                 view.expand(indexMouseArea)
            }
        }
    }
    model: fileSystemModel

    onExpanded {
       console.log("expanded :" + index)
    }
}
```

Comment: [`styleData.index`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#itemDelegate-prop) is available in delegates. For example, `onClicked: { view.expand(styleData.index); } `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution thanks to @mcchu:

Hellow,

When using delegate on a Column, how could I know the index of the Cell or Row selected if the user clicks on the delegateItem ?

Here is an example. The second Column is a MouseArea and I want to expand the currentIndex when the user clicks on the MouseArea:

```
TreeView {
    id: view
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"
        width: 300
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Permissions"
        role: "filePermissions"
        width: 100
        delegate : MouseArea {
            id:mous
            onClicked {
                view.expand(styleData.index);
            }
        }
    }
    model: fileSystemModel

    onExpanded {
       console.log("expanded :" + index)
    }
}
```